# Page not found after trying to add a new path to the urlpatterns of main urls.py file? (Mosh Python Tutorial)

Tags: django

I'm following Mosh's tutorial video on Python. He begins the django section (https://youtu.be/_uQrJ0TkZlc?t=18085) by installing django 2.1. I am able to open a development server the first time as he does:

```
pip install django==2.1
django-admin startproject pyshop .
python manage.py runserver #server works
```

Here are the steps he goes through to add a "products" app/path:

```
python manage.py startapp products
```

> Opens views.py from this new products folder and modifies code to this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

> Creates urls.py inside the products app/folder and adds this code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(' ', views.index)  # Here should have been '' and now fixed
]
```

> Opens the main urls.py in the pyshop folder and adds/modifies the end of the file like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

Mosh goes back to the server and adds /python to the url to get a page with "Hello World"
(https://youtu.be/_uQrJ0TkZlc?t=19220)

Upon trying to run the server again, I get Page not found error. Is there something I'm missing? I didn't figure it'd be a version issue since I made sure and installed the same 2.1 version.

As Jeffery and Daniel mentioned, I had an incorrect space and it needed to be an empty string in the products urls.py path. However, I'm still getting page not found error. Here's the exact error message if that helps:

> Using the URLconf defined in pyshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. admin/
> 2. products/
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: You've got a space on the path, rather than an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your url path in the products app/folder like this

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index)]
```

Remove the space in between